# Zooming and panning TextureView

Tags: android, zooming, pan, textureview

I tried many examples of how to zoom and pan Views. All they work with different views, imageViews. However I could not find any solution for panning zoomed TextureView. Is there anyone who implemented that feature?

Comment: TextureView#setTransform(Matrix transform)

Comment: @pskink It is only for zooming not panning

Comment: no,  it is for everything a Matrix supports

Comment: Yes. It really works like that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple views like ImageView in many implementations canvas is used. Instead of canvas in views whose onDraw() method is final use Matrix.
Example:

On ImageView:

```
 canvas.translate(x, y);
 canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
```

On TextureView:

```
 matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
 matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
```

Example in github: [link](https://github.com/Shuhrat-java/PanZoomPlayer)